# Precision not working or devcpp failure in long double 

Tags: c++, precision, double-precision

I have used this :

```
  long double f =79228162514264337593543950336.0;//maximum ; 2 ^ 96 because f is 12 bytes
  cout.precision(30);
  cout<<f;
```

But some numbers turns wrong . why ?

Comment: Please provide a complete program the demonstrates the problem. Please include the output that you expect, and the output that you actually receive.

Comment: I have copied this 3 line from main.

Comment: You never mentioned what platform/compiler you used. Wintel x86 would use native 80-bit floating numbers for `long double`, Sun used to emulate `long double` in software using 128-bits.

Comment: `long double` is typically 10 bytes long, not 12. 12 or 16 includes padding. The mantissa is 64 bits (but truly 64, there's no invisible 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What size of long double does your implementation provide (or, equivalently, what value does it show for LDBL_DIGITS)? It's often an 80-bit type with ~20 significant (decimal) digits. Note, in particular, that a floating point type will be divided between a mantissa (significand) and an exponent, so if it's 12 bytes overall, it will *not* have a 12-bit significand, so you can't expect to see 12 bytes worth of precision.

Comment: how can I found LDBL_DIGITS ?

Comment: you mean that I have never used 96 bits of double ?

Comment: @Parkhid: `#include <float.h>` (or, for C++ you can use `#include <limits>` and check `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`. I mean a 96-bit floating point type will have a sign bit, something like (say) 16 bits of exponent, and the rest as the mantissa. Thanks to normalization, you may get 1 more bit of precision than the stored mantissa size indicates, but that's about the best you can hope for.

Comment: cout<<std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10; => 15
cout<<std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10; => 18                          means what ?

Comment: digits10 -> Number of digits (in decimal base) that can be represented without change

Comment: it means that I cannot store this number into  a double ? am i true ?

Comment: @Parkhid: yes and no. You can store a number of that magnitude, but when you do so, it'll be rounded to ~18 significant digits.

Answer (score 2):

The correct suffix for `long double` literals is **`L`**:

```
long double f =79228162514264337593543950336.0L;
```